# ActivePerl ppm command error

Tags: perl, activeperl

I installed

```
On Windows 7 64-bit OS
ActivePerl 64bit 
Version 5.16.3.1603
on D disk as D:/perl64
```

I controlled Windows path, it is OK.

```
D:\perl64\site\bin; D:\perl64\bin;
```

When I open Git Bash commander and enter

```
ppm install DBI
```

or

```
ppm install DBD::mysql
```

It gives the error;

```
Can't locate ActivePerl/PPM/limited_inc.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
  /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
  /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
  /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /d/perl64/bin/ppm line 4. BEGIN
  failed--compilation aborted at /d/perl64/bin/ppm line 4.
```

I couldn't find any help or tutorial

Comment: looks like perl `5.8.8` and `5.16.3` clashing

Comment: You're not using ActivePerl. You're using `msys`'s Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using ActivePerl. You're using `msys`'s Perl. Presumably, it comes first in the path. You'll need to modify your path or edit `ppm.bat` to load the correct Perl.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @ikegami 's answer, msys has perl installed inside the `/bin` (or `/usr/bin` ) folder.

`perl.exe, perl5.8.8.exe, msys-perl5_8.dll, perldoc` etc..

Move these files to a backup folder, i.e. msys_perl

- `cd /bin`
- `mkdir msys_perl`
- `mv *perl* msys_perl/`

(*or you can delete them if you don't need them.*)

Now msys' Perl installation won't conflict with your ActiveState Perl version.

You might also need to copy `perl.exe` from your ActiveState Perl *bin* directory `/c/Perl64/bin/perl.exe` to `/usr/bin/`, to avoid getting `bad interpreter: No such file or directory` error message since ppm reads from `/usr/bin/perl`

- `cp /c/Perl64/bin/perl.exe /usr/bin/`

Comment: That a lot of work! Why not just change your path as I suggested?

Comment: I missed the "Presumably, it comes first in the path" in your answer... my apologies.   I think on first glance I thought you were suggesting to remove the directory in the PATH which contained the msys version of Perl

Comment: @ikegami  I modified the path so the correct version comes first, I verified with `perl -v`, but ppm still reads from msys perl.  Modifying ppm.bat _has_ to be done as well it seems.  I guess my solution will work without having to modify ppm.bat (which is also a read-only file)

Comment: Also, this could seriously break things that rely on the system Perl.